How to re-use default configs and override rest, and also unset any defaults if it is overridden as null in yaml
I have a chart where the values are like below:
defaultConfigs:
    keys1 : values1
    keys2: values2
    keys3: values3
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    keys100: values100
    
connectors:
  connector1:
    spec:
      keys1: override-this
      keys2: override-this-too
  connector2:
    spec:
      keys1: override-this
      keys2: null #should still override and remove keys2 without even taking it from default
  connector3:
     spec:
       keys1: override-this
       keys3: override-this-3-too


How can I make my template robust such that, with every connector I onlly define values which I want to override from default and keep everything else from the default configs as is as part of spec inside all connectors. However, I also have a case where if I override a value in connectors and keep it null, it should not even take it from default and unset it.
ex:
connectors:
  connector4:
    spec:
      keys1: override-this
      keys3: null

This should return connector 4 with all keys and values from default, while overriding keys1 and unsetting key3. How can I acheive this?

Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54742161/how-to-reference-values-in-yaml-file
